# Dependency Resolution in Swagger Startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, swagger

I'm trying to resolve an object that implements an `IMyConfiguration` interface during the startup of Swagger.

This is possible to do with the following snippet:

```
public class SwaggerConfig
{
    public static void Register()
    {
        var myConfig = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IMyConfiguration));

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableSwagger(c => { ... });
    }
}
```

Of course you need to make sure the container is initialized before Swagger registers itself for this to work.

I'm wondering whether there is a possible way to do the dependency resolution some other way, or that I'm going to have to live with this.